# UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput return key delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm using one of the new iOS 5 features for a UIAlertView. I create a UIAlertView like this:

```
UIAlertView *scanCode = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Some Title", @"") message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""), nil];
        [scanCode setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
        scanCode.tag = 1234;
        [scanCode show];
        [scanCode release];
```

The delegate I use now is:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 1234) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to simulate the enter key, so when the user hits return on the keyboard the same thing happens when pressing the OK button of the alert. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure your class conforms to the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol, make the `UIAlertView` a property for your class and add the following line to your setup code...

```
self.scanCode = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Some Title", @"") message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""), nil];
[self.scanCode setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
self.scanCode.tag = 1234;
//add this...
[[self.scanCode textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
[self.scanCode show];
```

By becoming the delegate for the input text field you can find out when the return key on the keyboard is pressed. Then in the .m file for your class you implement the delegate method below and tell the alert to disappear:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self.scanCode dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.scanCode.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Programming 15 hours a day really make obvious things forgotten ;-)

Comment: @jackslash Can you dismiss the parent `UIAlertView` in the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method if the `UIAlertView` isn't a property? (Besides ascending up the superview hierarchy?)

Comment: @jackslash Also, you should use `self.scanCode.firstOtherButtonIndex` instead of `0`. And make sure that the `UIAlertView` property is a weak reference, otherwise it'll be in memory after it disappears.

Comment: @zekel I think you'll need to keep the alert view as a property in order to dismiss it programatically. You can go up the view hierarchy as you suggest but I would favour writing the clearer code and making it a property. I would also agree that using a weak property is the best approach but if you were going to reuse the alert view theres little penalty for keeping it around versus not keeping it around as core animation releases the backing store when its not on screen.