# UIAlertView textfield capture onchange

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm trying to implement custom AlertView.

The idea is to have alertview with textfield and cancel button.

What i can't do is to check textfield live for entered characters. I know i can do it using `– alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` but i don't want another button. I wish to do the same just without button.

In android you can add listeners to textfields onchange.

Tried to do it using this uitextfield function, but it doesn't get called live or maybe i'm using it in a wrong way.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    if ([textField.text length] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

So how to do this properly?

Comment: Have you set the text field delegate?

Comment: Nop.. How and where should i do it? Sorry, I can't grasp the clear idea of delegate yet.

Comment: just see my answer it works fine...

Comment: FYI, iOS5 added the UITextField functionality to the UIAlertView. See this answer for an example on how its done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8994609/2263561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"New List Item", @"new_list_dialog")
                                                          message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
   UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    myTextField.delegate = self;
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
    [myAlertView show];
    [myAlertView release];
```

and textfield method

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@" %@", [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it says incompatible types in delegate method, from UItextfielddelegate to MYCLASSNAME. But thank you for your time looking to this. The prince already answered my question with working solution

Comment: that's good that you have found solution..but this code is working nice...i have tested it..probably you had forgot to set this line in your class .h file   UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>.

Comment: You are right, i haven't done that. Your solution is also working perfectly. However I will left the prince solution accepted as it was posted earlier. Thank you for your time helping !

Comment: +1 Because I think the delegate pattern is better in that particular case. And I changed the NSLog so it outputs the text that will be there after you left the method. Usually that makes more sense than checking the "old" string without changing the characters first.

Comment: Could you explain why this solution is better?

Comment: i am fully agreed with  Matthias Bauch,  it doesn't matter that who has posted first or last..and keep prince solution accepted as it is..but i am also suggest you to use the solution by delegate. notification is usually used when you don't have delegate method for this.

Comment: Just my opinion. If it's possible with delegation I usually go for delegation. No need to involve the notification center.

Answer (score 1):

You can add observer for the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` which will be posted whenever the `text` `changes` in `textfield`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(controlTextDidChange:)
   name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:[alert textField]];
```

selector is below:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
{
    if ([notification object] == [alert textField]) 
    {
      // [alert textField] has changed
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : `remove` `Observer` when `finish` doing

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification];
```

Comment: Greats. It works just as expected. Thank you very much. Guess I'll have to take a look at NotificationCentre reference.

Comment: and one more thing...just remove this observer when you don't need this.