# UITextfield totally secure without showing initial character for a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, security, uitextfield

I want to set uitextfield as total secure field. However, when user type one character, it is also shown on screen. I would like to hide the initial character also and when user type something (For eg. "A"), it show only secure text(. or *). How shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal for a solution. Use a second text store for the unhidden text, while replacing the textfield's text from your code, after changing the second text store. Listen to `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` as the text field's delegate, perform the changes mentioned, replace the characters with `●` and return NO in the delegate method.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do if it is uitextfield in alert view like this?     UITextField *textField;
    textField  =[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

Comment: You can set yourself to be the delegate of the alert view's text field in exactly the same manner. `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;`

Comment: I still see first character as unhidden immediately. If you don't mind, can you explain with code or demo project?

Answer (score 1):

this is the best solution for achieving behaviour that you describe:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == self.pinTextField) {
        NSString *currentText = textField.text;
        NSString *newText = [currentText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        textField.text = newText;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

don't forget to set correctly delegate to your UITextField:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind seeing dots instead asterisks, you can set the SecureTextEntry attribute to YES:

```
[yourUITextField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

Comment: It show initial character for a while. For my case, it should be completely hidden without showing for a while. How shall I do?

Comment: Sorry, I've misread you. Check this [link](http://appskingtechnologies.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/making-secure-textfield-in-ios.html) and [link](https://github.com/jstuckey/BashfulPasswordTextField). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. it helps. But How can I do if it is uitextfield in alert view like this?     UITextField *textField;
    textField  =[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

Comment: I think you should go for a custom `UIAlertView`. Check [link](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview). If you want to use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` instead, check my first [link](http://appskingtechnologies.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/making-secure-textfield-in-ios.html) above and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268358/uialertview-textfield-capture-onchange) answer

Comment: I still see first character as unhidden immediately. If you don't mind, can you explain with code or demo project? I have tried that link. But I wonder it doesn't work properly. I not sure why.